# Is possible multiple words search in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Its first time I am willing to add multiple search. I am not sure how it should be done. Should I use loop each word in search? or is there any mysql built in function there for it?

What I am thinking it should be like that?

```
 $strSearch = $this->input->post("search"); // would hold words etc hello word

 $arry = explode(" ", $strSearch);

 foreach($arry as $item){

 $this->db->query("select * from tbl where item like '%$item%');

}
```

Please advice.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot to search.

Iterating through your words is only a small part of the battle.  There is word order (Mac Office vs. Office Mac), ignoring common words (a, the), word variants like plurals.  Don't forget weighing and scoring your searches.

Try a library that's already done the heavy lifting like Zend Search Lucene.  See: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/207865/ or http://www.cmjackson.net/2009/02/17/how-to-use-zend_search_lucene-with-the-php-framework-codeigniter/.

Answer (score 0):

How it worked

I split the words and looped through for each to make an extra string and I executed the string through mysql query. it was working how i wanted.

```
$strSearch = $this->input->post("search"); // would hold words etc hello word

 $arry = explode(" ", $strSearch);

 foreach($arry as $item){


$xQuery .= " or name like '%$item%' or location like '%item'";

}


$this->db->query("select * from tbl where name like '$strSearch' or location like '$strSearch'  .$xQuery ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might look at MySQL natural language search.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html